# Generality of `foldr` or other higher order function

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Here's a simple function that takes a list and a number and works out if the length of the list is greater than that number.

e.g.

```
compareLengthTo [1,2,3] 3 == EQ
compareLengthTo [1,2] 3 == LT
compareLengthTo [1,2,3,4] 3 == GT
compareLengthTo [1..] 3 == GT
```

Note that it has two properties:

1. It works for infinite lists.
2. It is tail recursive and uses constant space.

```
import Data.Ord

compareLengthTo :: [a] -> Int -> Ordering
compareLengthTo l n = f 0 l
  where
    f c [] = c `compare` n
    f c (l:ls) | c > n = GT
               | otherwise = f (c + 1) ls
```

Is there a way to write `compareLengthTo` using `foldr` only?

Note, here's a version of `compareLengthTo` using `drop`:

```
compareLengthToDrop :: [a] -> Int -> Ordering
compareLengthToDrop l n = f (drop n (undefined:l))
  where
    f [] = LT
    f [_] = EQ
    f _ = GT
```

I guess another question is then, can you implement `drop` in terms of `foldr`?

Comment: what the function exactly does ? I didnt understand. It calculate if the given number is the length of the given list?

Comment: Sorry, I should proof read closer. Explanation and examples now included.

Comment: FYI, `Ordering` and `compare` and all those things are exported by the standard Prelude, so you shouldn't need to import `Data.Ord` for those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here ya go (note: I just changed one comparison, which makes it lazier):

```
compareLengthTo :: [a] -> Int -> Ordering
compareLengthTo l n = foldr f (`compare` n) l 0
  where
    f l cont c | c >= n = GT
               | otherwise = cont $! c + 1
```

This uses exactly the same sort of technique used to implement `foldl` in terms of `foldr`. There's a classic article about the general technique called [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Egmh/fold.pdf). You can also see a step-by-step explanation I wrote on the [Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative).

To get you started, note that `foldr` is being applied to *four* arguments here, rather than the usual three. This works out because the function being folded takes three arguments, and the "base case" is a function, `` (`compare` n) ``.

#### Edit

If you want to use lazy Peano numerals as J. Abrahamson does, you can count down instead of counting up.

```
compareLengthTo :: [a] -> Nat -> Ordering
compareLengthTo l n = foldr f final l n
  where
    f _ _ Zero = GT
    f _ cont (Succ p) = cont p

    final Zero = EQ
    final _ = LT
```

Comment: Thanks! Still need to get my head around the `foldl` using `foldr` thing, I suspected that was the approach but I think I'll need to pen+paper it to get a full understanding. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Clinton, if you've ever dealt with continuation passing style (CPS), the name `cont` should be suggestive.

Answer (score 1):

By it's very definition, `foldr` is not tail-recursive:

```
-- slightly simplified
foldr :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> ([a] -> r)
foldr cons nil []     = nil
foldr cons nil (a:as) = cons a (foldr cons nil as)
```

so you cannot achieve that end. That said, there are some attractive components of `foldr`'s semantics. In particular, it is "productive" which allows folds written with `foldr` to behave nicely with laziness.

We can see `foldr` as saying how to break down (catalyze) a list one "layer" at a time. If the `cons` argument can return without caring about any further layers of the list then it can terminate early and we avoid ever having to examine any more tails of the list---this is how `foldr` can act non-strictly at times.

Your function, to work on infinite lists, does something similar to the numeric argument. We'd like to operate on that argument "layer by layer". To make this more clear, let's define the naturals as follows

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

Now "layer by layer" more clearly means "counting down to zero". We can formalize that notion like so:

```
foldNat :: (r -> r) -> r -> (Nat -> r)
foldNat succ zero Zero = zero
foldNat succ zero (Succ n) = succ (foldNat succ zero n)
```

and now we can define something a bit like what we're looking for

```
compareLengthTo :: Nat -> [a] -> Ordering
compareLengthTo = foldNat succ zero where
  zero :: [a] -> Ordering
  zero [] = EQ  -- we emptied the list and the nat at the same time
  zero _  = GT  -- we're done with the nat, but more list remains

  succ :: ([a] -> Ordering) -> ([a] -> Ordering)
  succ continue []     = LT  -- we ran out of list, but had more nat
  succ continue (_:as) = continue as -- keep going, both nat and list remain
```

It can take some time to study the above to see how it works. In particular, note that I instantiated `r` as *a function*, `[a] -> Ordering`. The form of the function above is "recursion on the natural numbers" and it allows it to accept infinite lists so long as the `Nat` argument isn't...

```
 infinity :: Nat
 infinity = Succ infinity
```

Now, the above function works on this strange type, `Nat`, which models the non-negative integers. We can translate the same concept to `Int` by replacing `foldNat` with `foldInt`, written similarly:

```
foldInt :: (r -> r) -> r -> (Int -> r)
foldInt succ zero 0 = zero
foldInt succ zero n = succ (foldInt succ zero (n - 1))
```

which you can verify embodies the exact same pattern as `foldNat` but avoids the use of the awkward `Succ` and `Zero` constructors. You can also verify that `foldInt` behaves pathologically if we give it negative integers... which is about what we'd expect.

Comment: Isn't `foldl` tail recursive? And can't we write `foldl` in terms of `foldr`? If we do so, do we lose the tail recursive property?

Comment: @Clinton, a big part of it is that tail recursion isn't nearly as important in a lazy language as it is in a strict language. The closest notion in a strict language to some of what laziness does for Haskell is a generalization of tail recursion called tail recursion modulo cons. Another thing is that GHC knows how to avoid the consing altogether in some important situations, turning something tail recursive modulo cons into something tail recursive. Or something like that, anyway.

Comment: Could you explain why you chose to recast the problem in terms of the structure of the number instead of the structure of the list?

Comment: @Clinton To rephrase what dfeuer said: Yes, `foldl` defined in terms of `foldr` is still tail recursive. In Haskell, you cannot really say that "`foldr` is not tail recursive". (So I disagree with the reply above.) Instead, given the definition of `foldr` shown above, it depends on what `cons` does. In a language with eager evaluation, the arguments to `cons` would be evaluated first, so it couldn't be tail-recursive. But Haskell evaluates `cons` first, and if that reduces to something that is just a call to `foldr` (and in the `foldl` via `foldr` case, it does), then everything is fine.

Comment: @dfeuer Because part of the spec was being functional in face of infinite lists. Technically you could induct on both the list and the nat together to protect against all kinds of infinities, but that's a more complex induction principle.

Comment: @kosmikus I agree with what you say in more detail. It's never as clear in lazy evaluation what will actually happen, but it's clear that short of inlining even your example will at least interleave calls to foldr and cons.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Yes. You are right about the possible interleaving. But all these calls (from foldr to cons and vice versa) are still tail calls, so I would still argue that this instantiation of foldr is (indirectly) tail recursive.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson, take a look at my edit. To adapt my approach to potentially-infinite numbers just requires counting down instead of counting up.

Answer (score 1):

Have to participate into this coding competion:

"Prelude":

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Control.Applicative

compareLengthTo :: [a] -> Int -> Ordering
compareLengthTo l n = f 0 l
  where
    f c [] = c `compare` n
    f c (l:ls) | c > n = GT
               | otherwise = f (c + 1) ls
```

My first attempt was to write this

```
compareLengthTo1 :: [a] -> Int -> Ordering
compareLengthTo1 l n = g $ foldr f (Just n) l
  where
    -- we go below zero
    f _ (Just 0) = Nothing
    f _ (Just n) = Just (n - 1)
    f _ Nothing  = Nothing
    g (Just 0) = EQ
    g (Just _) = LT
    g Nothing  = GT
```

And it works for finite arguments:

```
prop1 :: [()] -> NonNegative Int -> Property
prop1 l (NonNegative n) = compareLengthTo l n === compareLengthTo1 l n

-- >>> quickCheck prop1
-- +++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

But it fails for infinite lists. Why?

Let's define a variant using peano naturals:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

foldNat :: (r -> r) -> r -> (Nat -> r)
foldNat succ zero Zero = zero
foldNat succ zero (Succ n) = succ (foldNat succ zero n)

natFromInteger :: Integer -> Nat
natFromInteger 0 = Zero
natFromInteger n = Succ (natFromInteger (n - 1))

natToIntegral :: Integral a => Nat -> a
natToIntegral = foldNat (1+) 0

instance Arbitrary Nat where
  arbitrary = natFromInteger . getNonNegative <$> arbitrary

instance Show Nat where
  show = show . (natToIntegral :: Nat -> Integer)

infinity :: Nat
infinity = Succ infinity

compareLengthTo2 :: [a] -> Nat -> Ordering
compareLengthTo2 l n = g $ foldr f (Just n) l
  where
    f _ (Just Zero) = Nothing
    f _ (Just (Succ n)) = Just n
    f _ Nothing  = Nothing
    g (Just Zero) = EQ
    g (Just _) = LT
    g Nothing  = GT

prop2 :: [()] -> Nat -> Property
prop2 l n = compareLengthTo l (natToIntegral n) === compareLengthTo2 l n

-- >>> compareLengthTo2 [] infinity
-- LT
```

After staring long enough we see that it works for *infinite numbers*, not infinite lists.
That's why [J. Abrahamson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28207462/1308058) used `foldNat` in his definition.
So if we *fold* the number argument, we will get function which works on infinite lists, but finite numbers:

```
compareLengthTo3 :: [a] -> Nat -> Ordering
compareLengthTo3 l n = g $ foldNat f (Just l) n
  where
    f (Just [])     = Nothing
    f (Just (x:xs)) = Just xs
    f Nothing       = Nothing
    g (Just [])     = EQ
    g (Just _)      = GT
    g Nothing       = LT

prop3 :: [()] -> Nat -> Property
prop3 l n = compareLengthTo l (natToIntegral n) === compareLengthTo3 l n

nats :: [Nat]
nats = iterate Succ Zero

-- >>> compareLengthTo3 nats (natFromInteger 10)
-- GT
```

---

`foldr` and `foldNat` are kind of functions which generalise structural recursion on the argument (*catamorphisms*). They have nice property that given *finite* inputs and total functions as arguments, they are also total i.e. always terminate.

That's why we `foldNat` in the last example. We assume that `Nat` argument is finite, so `compareLengthTo3` works on all `[a]` - even infinite.

Comment: The `foldr`-based solution I gave in my answer works for infinite lists. I think you may be missing something. It doesn't handle infinite numbers nearly as gracefully as a `zip`-style approach, however.

Comment: @dfeuer In your example you have a `c >= n` case to short circuit the computation. Without that case, the function works still for finite lists. I find these code paths a bit smelly, at least worth comment to justify their existence. -- Indeed `zip` approach would be the most elegant, but it can't be expressed in terms of `foldr` + `foldNat` so it would work for both "finite list + infinite number" and "infinite list + finite number" situations. And obviously there aren't approach which would terminate for "infinite number + infinite list" combo.

Comment: I've edited my answer; I expect you'll find the second implementation less smelly.